# In OS X, how would you know if an application is portable or installed?

Tags: portable-apps

In OS X Yosemite, how does one know if an application is a portable application (without installers, just run it) versus an application that was installed?

Comment: This is probaly a question better suited to Ask Different

Answer (score 2):

It is quite a difficult thing to find out, just from examining the application binary itself.

The surest way to check is to install another copy of OS X on a different partition, boot into that OS and try to run the app from there. That's how I do it. If it moans "this app was not properly installed", like VMWare, then you will know.

This is because the new OS will not have any of the extra drivers, and other gubbins, that the installer will have installed into the system folder.

At first glance, this may seem quite extreme way of finding out of the application is portable or not. However, it is not too hard, and only a small partition is required, as you only need it to install a bare minimum OS on. You aren't going to install any applications on it as it is only for test purposes.

You could also use an external hard drive if you don't want to mess with your install drive.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to check the documentation or the site you downloaded it from, but a lot of the time it can be hard to tell. I've seen apps that install just by dragging them to the apps folder (if I remember correctly, if you're logged in as an admin it doesn't ask for your password, but that was a few versions ago), but they still leave things behind.

If you really need to know, try checking various temp folders (library/application support, for example) other other user data storage folders for folders related to the application. If you find some, it's... probably not exactly portable. Depends on the contents - logs are okay, but data storage for other purposes is a bad sign. If worst comes to worst, simply try moving the application over to another computer and see if it runs normally. If no, it's not really portable.